# Token Mismatch exception when ajax Delete request sent in Laravel 5 when I change project folder

Tags: php, csrf, laravel-5

I used Dropzone.js to upload images. 
When I want to Delete image, I sent Ajax Delete request to Image Controller.

```
        myDropzone.on("removedfile", function(file) {      
            console.log(file.name);
            console.log(uploadedImages[file.name]);
            var csrf = $('input[name=_token]').val();
            // var csrf = $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content');
            console.log(csrf);
           var request = $.ajax({
                url: "/cms/image/"+uploadedImages[file.name],
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-Token': csrf ,
                    "Accept": "application/json"
                },
                type: "DELETE",
                data: {  "id": uploadedImages[file.name] },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    // alert('HTTP Error: '+errorThrown+' | Error Message: '+textStatus);
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                },
```

That method successfully sent to Controller with delete request in my old project.

But I merge in other project, I got the error.

> TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php

I don't understand why that exception occur. Please explain me about that. Thanks and respect to all geeks.

Comment: _But I merge in other project,_ explain this part.

Comment: I tested in my own sample Laravel-5 project . when it success, I added to Main project. Copy controller , view , model and other necessary files and add to Main project.

Comment: in console, check for the `X-CSRF-Token` in header that was sent. my guess is, it won't be present.

Comment: Just a test: try to send the csrf toke value into the ajax data's json:  `data: {  "id": uploadedImages[file.name], "_token":  csrf}`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try putting the token in the sent data

```
data: {  
   "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
   "id": uploadedImages[file.name] 
},
```

Comment: hey, i did use your solution but it doesn;t seem to work for me..if you can please help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39033178/ajax-delete-not-working-in-laravel-5-2

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem but it wasn't related to the CSFR, it was due to the file size being bigger than 2MB..

Answer (score -2):

By default laravel comes with csrf token verification middleware.

**Solution:**

You can disable it by removing middleware registration of csrf token from `kernel.php` in Http folder.

```
protected $middleware = [
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse',
    'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
    'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',
  //'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
];
```

Comment: I know that way , but i don't want to use. CsrfToken is set for protection. Thanks

Comment: Then you have to pass csrf token with your request data. try by adding _token parameter in your request data.

Comment: Making Laravel (and any other soft) less secure is not a good way and for sure this solution isnt useful!