# Ajax delete not working in laravel 5.2

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel-5

I'm trying to `delete` a record in `mysql` in `laravel` application. But it shows **TokenMismatchException** error. I am not able to find why its throwing error. It would be great if anyone can help out..

here's **view** code: (I don't have a form)

```
<a href="{{url('/page/'.$Ids->id)}}" class="remove-entry">
  <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
</a>
```

And here's **jQuery AJAX call**:

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove-entry', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        type: 'DELETE',
        data: {
            "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"
        },
        success: function(res) {
            console.log('removed');
        }
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

I tired the following code but it doesn't work probably because it needs to have value `token` which I suppose is to be fetched from form. But as I already mentioned above, I DON'T have a form set-up. So how can I put the `token` value in that case?

```
headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token}
```

I understand the problem I'm facing is not new or unique, but it surely is different from the questions that it is supposedly considered duplicate of. Also, the code worked fine earlier but its creating issues in new project

Comment: have you take any token field in html, which you pass in data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel 5.2 valid ajax request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34572347/laravel-5-2-valid-ajax-request)

Comment: @SandipPatel no, how should i do that? Also, in my old project, in the exact same situation, it worked fine.

Comment: @vitr I suppose the link you 're talking about is using form data. And I already mentioned I don't have a form setup.How is it duplicate then? Also I did search for it for quite sometime and tried the solutions. since it didn't work, I posted it as a question. Hope that's okay with the community.

Comment: sorry, wrong link, just see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34572347/laravel-5-2-valid-ajax-request
and add `headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},`

Comment: @vitr tried that, but how should I setup `token` in the that?

Comment: it's right in the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#csrf-protection
same `{{ csrf_token }}`

Comment: @vitr that again is using FORM! if you don;t mind, can you please remove the duplication request. Maybe someone else would have a solution..

Comment: are you have CSRF token issue or some thing else ..?

Comment: you don't understand how DELETE works at all, there is no data, add the token in the header, so easy, man

Comment: @MArfan yes CSRF token issue `TokenMismatchException`

Comment: you can send request without CSRF token as well. I post answer answer for that.

Comment: @vitr I know its damn easy. since it isn't working, I am here with a question.

Comment: @vitr maybe I'm misunderstanding you. Would be great if you can show it with your code.

Comment: @vitr I did try your way. Added header and did as you mentioned..still the same error :(

Comment: sorry, try this $.ajax({ url: this.href, type: 'DELETE', headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}' }, success: function(res) { console.log('removed'); } });

Comment: have you got something like this in the source code? `headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': 'k5MoGFMrIAW7yC8yqTArekcrSxPFfN46SfXNvcvE' }`

Comment: @vitr no, how can I get that?

Comment: you updated you question and put `token` there, you must put `'{{ csrf_token() }}'` instead, this is  laravel helper function, and it doesn't  care have you got form or not

Comment: i used as you mentioned in comment. `headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : '{{ csrf_token() }}' }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121322/discussion-between-vitr-and-newbee).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to send Ajax Request without CSRF token in laravel.
Goto : app/Http/Middlewares/VerifyCsrfToken.php

```
protected $except = [
    'request/send_ajax',  /// Enter your route post link here
    'request/send_ajax1'
];
```

Now you can post ajax request without token

OR

Simple insert a META tag on the page where you will do the Ajax request and default middleware will check for csrf_token.

OR

```
$.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo url("yourrequest"); ?>",
        type: "POST",
         headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        data:'column='+column+&id='+id,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(msg);
        }        
   });
```

Work on Laravel5.2

Comment: isn't this like disabling the CSRF? Pardon me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes this is solution for disabling the CSRF for specific route

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to generate **app key**, type in your cmd:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Then write the following line (with the generated key) to the .env file

```
APP_KEY=your_key
```

If this not works you may create in your view js variable:

```
var token = '{{Session::token()}}';
```

And then instead of using header try:

```
$.ajax({
          method:"post",
          url:yoururl,
          data:{
            _token:token,
          }
 }).done(function(msg) {

});
```

The third option can be that something is going wrong while your **user logs into your app**. Then you need to show the login code from controller.

Hope it will help :)

Comment: `var token = '{{Session::token()}}';` is saved as string, how can I get the value of it?

Comment: You mean how to get value of this var in your js file? You need to place this variable at the end of your code in your view, and then just simply pass it in your ajax function in data `_token:token`. It's normal variable which you can use in your js file. For example you can check it out by displaying it, in your js file write console.log(token) and check out your browser console.